# Open Second Link on a page using Jquery

Tags: jquery, window

I am trying to open a link on my page in a new page with Jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a:eq(0)").attr("target","_blank");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
<p class="intro">My name is Donald</p>
<a href="http://google.com">I live in Duckburg</a>
<p>My best friend is Mickey</p>
Who is your favourite:
<ul id="choose">
<li>Goofy</li>
<li>Mickey</li>
<li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**(copied wrong code on last edit this is the code I am using now. This is executed at page load time via a javascript that calls a bunch of other load time things.)**

I have all the other code in place, and this continues to not work properly.

But this code still opens the second link in the same window. Can anyone help?

Comment: hej in this example you are executing the code before the links. is this the case in the real app?????

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your script in $(document).ready(function( . . .your stuff }); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `eq(2)` to `eq(1)`, because `eq()` starts from index `0` and also make sure you change attributes after DOM is ready

```
<html>
<script>
$(function(){    $("a:eq(1)").attr("target", "_blank");  });
</script> 
<body>
<a href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a><br />
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Downvoter, do you care to explain your vote, so I can improve my answer?

Comment: @TimBJames: Ah, that makes sense :/

Answer (score 1):

Wait until **after** the link actually exists before trying to modify it and start counting from `0` not `1`.

(Untested):

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a><br />
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<script>
$("a:eq(1)").attr("target", "_blank");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ive modified my code to kinda incorporate several suggestions. But it still doesn't do what it should am I still missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`eq` references an array of elements. Arrays start with the index of 0, so you will want to look for the element with an index of 1

```
$(function(){
    // wait for the DOM to load.
    $("a").eq(1).attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Look here for reference http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Here is a working example based on your code. http://jsfiddle.net/3wz9a/2/